# Tracking Event Processor - Retry Execption originating from Event Handlers

Tags: axon

I am trying to configure an `ErrorHandler` for a `TrackingEventProcessor` so that *any* exception in my `@EventHandler` annotated method will be retried.
Currently using Axon Framework 4 and looking how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to set the `PropagatingErrorHandler` as the `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` in this case.
Know that there are two error handling levels within a given Event Processor, namely:

1. The `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler`, catching the exceptions thrown from within your `@EventHandler` annotated methods. This defaults to a `LoggingErrorHandler` instance, which logs the exception.
2. The `ErrorHandler`, catching the transaction exceptions of the given `EventProcessor`. This defaults to a `PropagatingErrorHandler`, which rethrows the exceptions.

The `TrackingEventProcessor` (TEP) `EventProcessor` implementation is the one which will retry events with a certain (unconfigurable) back-off, if the configured `ErrorHandler` throws an exception.

If you want to retry on *every* exception (which might be a debatable approach anyhow), you'd thus want to enter the retry scheme of the TEP. To achieve this, you simply should configure the `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` to also be a `PropagatingErrorHandler`. I'd recommending reading the [Reference Guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors#error-handling) on the matter too, to get a better idea of how to configure this.

Comment: so when you say ListenerInvocationErrorHandler catches the exception thrown from event handlers does it means all user defined exceptions thrown from event handlers will be caught and logged and does TEP always retries for transaction failures automatically or do we need to configure an error handler for it?

Comment: "so when you say ListenerInvocationErrorHandler catches the exception thrown from event handlers does it means all user defined exceptions thrown from event handlers will be caught and logged" - Yes, that's the case, as the `LoggingInterceptor` is the default configured `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler`.

Comment: "does TEP always retries for transaction failures automatically or do we need to configure an error handler for it? " - Yes, that is the case, if you haven't specified anything. Since it is the default behaviour.

Comment: @Steven, what is the reasoning behind the unconfigurable back-off? Wouldn't it make sense to just stop retrying after a certain amount of retries and rollback the transaction somehow?

Comment: Configuring this behavior has indeed be discussed and actually is on the backlog. The reason it hasn't been prioritized is that in face of back-offs, other processor threads are able to claim the token. Thus, if your microservice A fails, microservice B (when both run the Event Processor) will automatically see it can claim the token and proceed. Hence, the majority of issue would automatically be resolved through this process.

Comment: @Steven, what if an unrecoverable error arises and Axon keeps retrying? How can we configure that this error will just get sent up to for example the controller?

Comment: From the Event Processing perspective, there is no way to get back to the controller. The Event Processors handle events entirely separate from any REST operation, typically. If you look at REST, you can roughly do Writes and Reads. Thus, you can do Commands and Queries. As such, only the results of exception command handling or query handling would go directly back to the endpoint.

Comment: Added, it's an internal issue to your application as event handling is disjunct in time and space from when/where the event happened. As such, it's a monitoring requirement in your system landscape to spot these and resolve these. A first stab would be logging the exception and having some notifiers on the logs to tell your (Dev)Ops they should act. This is in part why Axon defaults to logging and exception and proceeding. It proceeds since events can be replayed anyhow. So if something goes amiss, the Event Processor can start again.